# Current user did not login to the application! in boilerplate

Tags: angular, aspnetboilerplate, boilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I am download **angular** + **asp.net** core template(v2x) from net.

Successfully create database and run the API layer, then build angular application and run using "npm start".

Both application runs successfully.

When I login to application by default name(admin) and password(123qwe), I am successfully login, but my data not get selected and it's give me error when i click on any tab, please refer following screen :

[image]

In console it give me this error :

```
 "{"result":null,"targetUrl":null,"success":false,"error":{"code":0,"message":"Current user did not login to the application!","details":null,"validationErrors":null},"unAuthorizedRequest":true,"__abp":true}"
```

Please help me for my problem

Comment: It seems your problem are related to the source code you used to create your project. I do not know where did you get it. If it is from some kind of version control system or something similar, you should ask this question to the author(s) of the code. Otherwise, please create a small sample to create this problem on the cloud ides or in similar platform(s).

Comment: I am getting code from "https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates" where I choose ASP.Net Core +angular(v2x), this code run smoothly in another system, but in my system they create an issue. i am following same steps for both system